# Animate UIView from center to top using autolayout constraings swift 2.1

Tags: ios, animation, swift2, xcode7

I want to animate UITextField from center to top of the view on a button click. TextField has following constraints

[image]

Following is the code to on button click to move textfiled to top.

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
   self.txtfield.center.y = 10
  }
```

above code works, textfiled moved to top but when I go back and come to this view again textfield is again in center. I am new to swift I want that once textfield is moved to top it should stay on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get a reference to the constraint in your code. Then you change the constant value of the constraint instead.

I have added the code to move the text field to top in `viewDidLoad` but you will of course have this code in your button action. You have to drag from the "Align Center Y" and into your view controller in order to create a reference to the constraint. The reason why I subtract 10 is because your example and intention was to have a 10 points margin from the top. And take note that I "reversed" the first and second item like this:

[image]

Remember that when you use auto layout, the frame and center and the size of the views bounds get set by auto layout constraints.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldYAlignConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         UIView.animateWithDuration(1.2) { () -> Void in
        self.centeraligntConstraint.constant = -400
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()// to animate layout constraint
    }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Snusmumrikken

Comment: @MuhammadSaifullah No problem. See the updated code and image example.

Comment: It is moving top but textfiled is not animating. it just jumps to the top.  Can you please confirm in your emulator that textfiled is also animating.. here is my code. 
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5) {
    yconstriant.constant= -300// just a test. textfiled jumps but not animate. 
  }

Comment: never mind. found the solution, need to add view.layoutifneed in animation to animate costraint :) edited the answer